# Convert a json file to a multi row with a matrix of all the nested objects

Tags: python, json, bash, jenkins, groovy

In order to use the Extended Choice Parameter Jenkins plugin, I need to create a file containing a matrix with several options, such as:

```
    Country     State   City
    USA         FL      Miami
    USA         FL      Tampa
    USA         FL      Jacksonville
    USA         NY      NYC
    USA         NY      Rochester
    USA         NY      Syracuse
```

Given this list could be quite a challenge to maintain, I thought of creating a json file, for example (:

```
["USA":       
 [{        
      "NY": [
            "NYC",
            "Rochester",
            "Syracuse"
    ],
    "FL": [
            "Miami",
            "Tampa",
            "Jacksonville",
   etc...
```

The question is how to convert a JSON file with many nested objects to a matrix in which the last column is always the deepest nested object?

Alternatively, is there another way to keep the parameters' file maintainable?

I can use bash, python etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Your sample is an invalid JSON value

Comment: Known issue, It is just an example.

Comment: Provide a proper example then

Comment: @DavidKon Are you open for an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native language of Jenkins and it's plugins is Groovy. And it's always your best bet for general programming. Given that you have your states and towns correctly formatted in a JSON format you can use Groovy, json to process it. Here is the example code:

```
import groovy.json.*
str="""
{
    "country": {"name": "USA",
    "states": [
        {
            "name": "NY",
            "towns": [
                "NYC",
                "Rochester",
                "Syracuse"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "FL",
            "towns": [
                "Miami",
                "Tampa",
                "Jacksonville"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}

"""

jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
gstr=jsonSlurper.parseText(str)

stateRow=[]
gstr.country.states.each{    
        it.towns.each{tn->
        row =[]
        row.add(gstr.country.name)
        row.add(it.name)
        row.add(tn)
        stateRow.add(row.join(','))
    }
}
stateRow.each{
println it
}
return stateRow
```

This code returns a table with the town names being the last column

```
USA,NY,NYC
USA,NY,Rochester
USA,NY,Syracuse
USA,FL,Miami
USA,FL,Tampa
USA,FL,Jacksonville
Result: ['USA,NY,NYC', 'USA,NY,Rochester', 'USA,NY,Syracuse', 'USA,FL,Miami', 'USA,FL,Tampa', 'USA,FL,Jacksonville']
```

Comment: The output of your code is not the expected one. I need an array that for each town, I get a single row containing the Country, State and town.
For example:

     US,FL,MIAMI
     US,FL,SYRACUSE
     US,NY,NYC
     US,NY,ROCHESTER
     FRANCE,NORMANDY.CHERBOURG
     FRANCE,NORMANDY.ROUEN
     ITALY,ABRUZZO,PESCARA

Comment: @DavidKon thank you for the clarification of the desired output format. I have updated my answer to match your required format.